# Zend Custom ViewScript for Form not rendering file element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I created a custom viewscript for a zend form. In the form, there is a file element. When I run the code `echo $this->element->elementname->renderViewHelper()` it works fine on all elements except the file element. When I run the following code on my file element within my custom viewscript, i get the following error: `Uncaught exception 'Zend_Form_Element_Exception' with message 'Decorator by name ViewHelper does not exist'`

```
<?php if($this->element->avatarimage->hasErrors()):?>
        <div class="control-group error">
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="control-group">
    <?php endif;?>
        <label for="avatarimage" class="control-label">Avatar Image</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php echo $this->element->avatarimage->renderViewHelper();?>
            <?php if($this->element->avatarimage->hasErrors()):
                    $messages = $this->element->avatarimage->getMessages();
                    $messages = array_values($messages);
                    $message  = $messages[0];
                    echo '<span class="help-inline">'.$message.'</span>';
                endif;
            ?>              
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I incorporate my file element into my custom form viewscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?php echo $this->element->avatarimage;?>
```

Comment: This semi solves my problem. When I do this, I get the extra html content attached to the avatarimage element (the dt's and dd's). With every other element, calling renderViewHelper returns just the input html.

Comment: You need to remove the the decorator from the element at the form class. For example $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');

Comment: BTW you can also remove other decorators : $element->removeDecorator('label') $element->removeDecorator('htmlTag'); You can read a more about decorators here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html

Comment: i tried removing the decorators from the avatarimage element and used your code. still not working.

Comment: But what do you mean with "still not working"? do you still see the additional html generated?

Comment: It works! There was a naming confliction since i have a module the same name as my custom library.

Answer (score 3):

This should definitely work.

```
<? echo $this->element->avatarimage->renderFile(); ?>
```

Comment: God Bless you wherever you are. That saved so much of my time.